# Questions on what to use for cross-platform development app (with Linux server) using C#

Tags: c#, .net

After couple years of c++ programming, I decided to go with C# and decided to create a cross-platform app which would work on mobile and pc just for the sake of learning experience, however I stumbled into couple problems on deciding how to build it around using all the .Net eco-system. The app would be a status list report with pictures, so it should work on web too then.

Since the app will be on web (never did with web stuff, except touched like one or two times php ages ago) and as application for both mobile and Windows applications. I have Linux server lying around so I would like to use that as server with MYSQL database, so I guess ASP.Net Core with RESTful the way to go with it?

For mobile app I am planning to Xamarin.Forms, but not sure what to do with Windows application.

What exatcly things I need to use to achive my specified use-case (cross-platform client app, with Linux server and would work via Web too)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I guess ASP.Net Core with RESTful the way to go with it?

Yes, ASP.NET Core Web API is the most obvious choice.

> For mobile app I am planning to Xamarin.Forms, but not sure what to do with Windows application.

Xamarin.Forms support UWP (Windows Universal Platform). So if you're okay that the Windows version of your application will only work on Windows 10, you don't need anything else.

If you also want to support older versions of Windows, Xamarin.Forms is planning to support WPF, but [it won't happen any time soon](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85747/xamarin-forms-feature-roadmap/p1). So for now, you would have to have a separate WPF UI.